# redirect и вызов в чем отличие

Tags: java

В контроллере есть метод:

```
@GetMapping("/books")
public String showBooks() {
...
return ...
}
```

В чем будет отличие

```
return "redirect:/books";
```

от

```
return "books";
```

и тот и другой делают переход на страницу books.html, т.е. возвращают эту страницу
А в чем разница?

Answer (score 1):

`return "books";` - ищет шаблон с названием "books", обрабатывает его и возвращает.

`return "redirect:/books";` - видит `redirect:`, это значит что нужно сказать браузеру что бы перешел на `localhost:8080/users`. Редирект используется для перенаправления на другой адрес. У вас адреса совпадают и вы перенаправляете на самого себя.

Comment: что значит на другой адрес, а он разве щас не на нем находится. Насколько я понимаю все действия происходят по адресу localhost:8080/users/... Смысл на него возвращаться если он и так там

Comment: например, books.html лежит в проекте в папке templates/books/ относительно корня webapp. Что надо писать return "books" или return "redirect:/books"?

Comment: в вашем случае нужно написать `return "books";`. Редирект нужен например когда вы добавили новую книгу и после сохранения вам нужно перейти на страницу этой новой книги, тогда будете использовать `return "redirect:/books/"+id;`

Comment: я не знаю зачем вы возвращаетесь на тот же адрес)